# Windows 11 no sound in secure boot

Tags: audio, secure-boot, windows-11

I have Windows 11, but I have no sound in secure boot. WHen it's enabled, I went to Device Manager, and all the sound drivers said: "Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this device." When secure boot is disabled, sound works fine.
Drivers: Realtek(R) Audio, Bose Qc35 Stereo, BRKSTN SPKR Stereo

Comment: Use a signed device driver.  If the device came with Windows 10 then the driver exists

Comment: @Ramhound I have Realtek, Bose QC35, and Brookstone drivers.

Comment: All of those should be signed by their respective publisher.  You will have to remove the unsigned driver, install the signed driver, and perform a reboot.  You could, of course, revert back to Windows 10, and wait for compatible drivers to be published.  Since Secure Boot must be enabled for Windows 11 that is really your only other choice.

Comment: @Ramhound I have installed another major release of Windows 11, so I have no way back.

Comment: You have 10 days to revert back to Windows 10.  The first Insider Preview build of Windows 11 is only 7 days old.  Regardless, due to the Secure Boot requirement, you really don't have another choice other than to use signed drivers (or revert back to Windows 10).

Comment: Once I install a version of Windows twice, there's no going back. @Ramhound. In Windows.old is the previous Windows 11.

Comment: This will work for an unknown amount of time, it most likely will not work after any  Windows 11 build in the Release Preview channel. 
 Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup` create a key called `LabConfig` under that create a DWORD (32-bit) value called `BypassSecureBootCheck`with a value of 1.  You should be able to disable Secure Boot at this point, I will again point out, you must use signed drivers if you on Windows 11 with Secure Boot enabled.   **I am not even sure that key will work**